# Unable to upload a file via the XMLHttpRequest object but upload status changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest

I want to upload a file within Codeigniter application. I am using the `XMLHttpRequest` object to upload the file and update a progress bar to show the file's upload status.The problem is that the file is not being uploaded but the progress bar show progress from 0% all up to 100%. You'll find my code below:

> View:

```
<script>
  function upload_video_Data(a) {      
    var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById('posting_comment_'+a)[0]);
    fd.append("file_m_id",a);
    var bar = $('.bar');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();        
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);

    xhr.open("POST", "dashboard/do_upload_video");
    xhr.send(fd);  

    function uploadProgress(evt) {
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
        document.getElementById('progressNumber_'+a).innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
        $("#status_"+a).animate( { width: percentComplete.toString()+"%"}, 5);
      }   
    }

    setTimeout(function(){ remove_video_progress_bar(a); }, 1000);       
  }
</script>

<form name="posting_comment" id="posting_comment_<?=$row1['id']?>" method="post">
  <span style="margin-left: 8px;" id="video_<?=$row1['id']?>" >
    <input type="file" name="save_movie_<?=$row1['id']?>" class="movie_field" id="movie_<?=$row1['id']?>" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="<?=$row1['id']?>"/> 
  </span>   
  <input type="button" class="postbtn" id="submit_movie_<?=$row1['id']?>" value="Upload Video File" onclick = "return upload_video_Data(<?=$row1['id']?>)"/> 

  <div id="progress_video_<?=$row1['id']?>" style="background:transparent;border:none;"> 

    <div class="progress" style="background: transparent;border:none;">
      <div id="status_<?=$row1['id']?>" style="background:#0066cc; width:0%;"></div>
      <div id="progressNumber_<?=$row1['id']?>" class="percent" style="background: transparent;border:none;color:blue;">0%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: transparent;border:none;" id="ext_error_<?=$row1['id']?>"> </div>  
</form>
```

> Controller:

```
public function do_upload_video($a) {    
  $lecture_id=$this->input->post('form_id');
  $output_dir = "./uploads/";
  $type="video";

  $fileName = $_FILES["save_movie_".$lecture_id]["name"];
  $extn = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["save_movie_".$lecture_id]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName)) {
  } else {        
  }   
}
```

Comment: This doesnt really answer your question, but it is a solution.  I use JqueryForm (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to manage my uploads.  Works well in all browsers and managers progress updates pretty well

Comment: @QBM5- Can u please tell me how to work with  the above code

Comment: No, thats why I said it wasnt really an answer, just a suggestion.  There is good documentation on the site